# Muliple Selects Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

here my code:

Home

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
<select  data-theme="a" id="listazza" multiple="multiple" data-inline="true" 
data-native-menu="true" >
    <option>NAME</option>
        <option  id="MYID">NAME</option>
        <option  id="MYID">NAME</option>
        <option  id="MYID">NAME</option>
        <option  id="MYID">NAME</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

All works well, but when I select multiple items, the result isn't like this [Multiple selects](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html)

The number of selected items appear correctly but items are all displayed so my button is enlarged outside screen width!
I've tried with all JQ css like .ui-select and similar but nothing works for me!
What can I do?

sorry my italian english :D

Comment: Is there a live example you can share or create a jsfiddle of your problem?

Comment: yes, the left image is what I want to obtain, and the right is my result: http://goo.gl/rO2OA

Answer (score 0):

Change the meta tag - like so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: This is not an auto-scale issue. Pls read the question carefully.